# How to select rows from a database that do not match a criteria, unless they do match another

Tags: sql

I'm not sure how to even word this question. so I will go straight into an example.

I need to run an SQL query that follows something like this

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
WHERE id > 1000
AND name not like 'abc_%'
UNLESS name like 'abc_def%'
```

So in the results:

- rows where 'name' is 'abc_zyxdef' or 'abc_lmnop' for example will NEVER be returned irrespective of the id.
- rows where 'name' is 'abc_defghij' or 'abc_def123' will be returned IF the id is over 1000
- rows where 'name' is anything else will be returned IF the id is over 1000

is this possible in one statement?

Thanks

Comment: Based on comments beneath the other answer (which is now deleted), I think you should modify your question to remove the ambiguity.  Some could read this as "So rows where name = abc_zyxwvuts will be excluded but **abc_defghij and zyx_wvuts will be included *only* if the id is over 1000**"

Comment: That is what I am after. I do not want abc_defghij if the id is 999, but I do if it is 1001

Comment: Right, but what if name = abc_zyxwvuts and id is 999?  In other words, does the id have to be over 1000 no matter what name is?  Is that an overarching requirement?  You see my point?

Comment: I see what you are saying. I will edit the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not this?

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
WHERE id > 1000
AND (name not like 'abc_%'
OR name like 'abc_def%')
```

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks for your help